# Error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `?', expecting `.' in monodevelop

Tags: c#, monodevelop

This is the code that give me the error:

```
s.GetWeight(out weightInLb, out weightInG, out weightInOz, out bool? isStable);

 Error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `?', expecting `.'
```

This code calls a function GetWeight, here is the code:

```
 public void GetWeight(out decimal? weightInLb, out decimal? weightInG, out decimal? weightInOz, out bool? isStable)
```

What am I doing wrong? Please help!

EDIT

If I replace the ? with a . I get the error:

```
Error CS0117: `bool' does not contain a definition for `isStable'
```

Comment: You are trying to use language features which are not supported by older C# compilers.

Comment: @mjwills what version supports this?

Comment: https://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/

Comment: The problem might not be the nullability here but the fact that you're trying to declare the variable as part of the out parameter, which may not be supported by (that specific version of) the mono compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to use [out variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7#out-variables) and it's just not supported by your compiler. So do it in old fashioned way

```
bool? isStable;
s.GetWeight(out weightInLb, out weightInG, out weightInOz, out isStable);
```